# React: How to send data to parent as an object and how to use it?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-props, react-component

I made a date calculation and I stored `year`, `month` & `day` values in an object and I wanna send this object to the parent `App.js` and then send that data to my other child component `Modal.js` as a `prop` and show it in the popup message (the calculation result) but while receiving the data in the `App.js` I don't know how to use it / store it and send it to the other component.

**UserAgeForm.js**

```
const onSubmitHandler = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const calcAge = () => {
        let calcYear;
        let calcMonth;
        let calcDay;

        if (currentDate < birthDay || currentMonth < birthMonth) {
            calcDay = currentDate + currentMonthDays - birthDay;
            calcMonth = currentMonth + 11 - birthMonth;
            calcYear = currentYear - 1 - birthYear;
        } else {
            calcDay = currentDate - birthDay;
            calcMonth = currentMonth - birthMonth;
            calcYear = currentYear - birthYear;
        }
        //  here I'm trying to send the data
        props.userData = {
            calcYear,
            calcMonth,
            calcDay,
        };
    };
    calcAge();
};
```

**App.js**

```
function App() {
    const receivedUserData = {
        // how to do it
    };
    const allUserData = {
        // how to do it
    };
    return (
        <>
            <UserAgeForm userData={receivedUserData} />
            {ReactDOM.createPortal(
                <Modal resultData={allUserData} />,
                document.getElementById("modal")
            )}
        </>
    );
}
```

Comment: Read up on [lifting state](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html). You could pass ```onSubmit``` as a prop to your form, and define in the parent component to do what you want with there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Declare some state in `App` to hold the state value and pass the state and callbacks to update it down as props to children. This pattern is commonly known as [Lifting State Up](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html).

Example:

```
function App() {
  const [userData, setUserData] = React.useState({});

  return (
    <>
      <UserAgeForm setUserData={setUserData} />
      {ReactDOM.createPortal(
        <Modal resultData={userData} />,
        document.getElementById("modal")
      )}
    </>
  );
}
```

UserAgeForm

```
const onSubmitHandler = (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  let calcYear;
  let calcMonth;
  let calcDay;

  if (currentDate < birthDay || currentMonth < birthMonth) {
    calcDay = currentDate + currentMonthDays - birthDay;
    calcMonth = currentMonth + 11 - birthMonth;
    calcYear = currentYear - 1 - birthYear;
  } else {
    calcDay = currentDate - birthDay;
    calcMonth = currentMonth - birthMonth;
    calcYear = currentYear - birthYear;
  }
        
  props.setUserData({
    calcYear,
    calcMonth,
    calcDay,
  });
};
```